# Should TeXLive installation take 21+ hours? (Windows)

Tags: installing

First of all, this is not really a question but rather a comment to specify / add to the following question:
[Should TeXLive installation take 17+ hours? (Windows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/271931/should-texlive-installation-take-17-hours-windows/636253)

1. I downloaded the iso. Download went fast. Install failed twice giving an error message. (Sadly I can't remember which one)
2. My internet connection is good. I'm able to watch netflix in the meantime (which - of course - I only did for testing purposes)
3. I picked several download mirrors, all with the same slow connection
4. My PC ain't too slow. I'm running a dual boot and the installation went super fast on xubuntu. (i.e. less than 20 minutes)
   EDIT: 5. Download behavior is odd. See attached screenshot at the end of the posting.

So is there a solution to the other guy's (and my) problem? And by "solution", I don't mean a workaround. I already tried the workaround (downloading the iso) but it failed. I'm at 1083/4318  right now after 6:53:27. Estimated time left for installation is 27hrs.

Thank you!

P.S.: Sorry to all you folks that have to read the same question again. I really didn't mean to ask this AGAIN, but some of the older contributers on here thought it was a new question (really, it's brand new, they promise!) rather than a specification, therefore deleted my other comment and here we are. So I was kind of "forced" to ask the same question as the other guy, thus filling up this wonderful forum with annoying double-posts (which in other forums would rightfully get deleted for sure!). I wonder why these folks didn't delete the other 4-5 comments that didn't actually present a solution to the problem. Maybe it's because those users have been on here for a longer time? We'll never find out... And YES of course I'm p***ed.

Screenshot of download rate: https://ibb.co/thw5PBQ

Comment: Of course it shouldn't

Comment: I installed on windows the (full) texlive2022 in less than two hours.

Comment: Hey Ulrike, what type of installation did you use? Do you remember the download mirror by chance? Grüße, Günni

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry, but “*less than two hours*” sounds suboptimal at best when these days *one hour* is enough to reinstall Windows, then download and install massively bloated Adobe and Autodesk suites each about five times the size of full TeX Live distro, then restore the settings from a cloud backup and there still will be some spare time to download and install numerous smaller apps with scoop/winget. The TeX Live installer is a pain to use and it's much faster and robust to unpack and setup portable instance or initialize a docker image, at least on modern Windows.